# calculate the mean of column and also the comments in next column

Tags: r

I want to calculate the mean of column and and also concatenate the texts in second column output.

for example in below i want to calculate the mean of C1 and then concatenate all texts in C1T in next column if there is more than one text in C1T.

```
df <- data.frame(A1 = c("class","type","class","type","class","class","class","class","class"),
                 B1 = c("b2","b3","b3","b1","b3","b3","b3","b2","b1"),
                 C1=c(6,    NA, 1,  6,  NA, 1,  6,  6,  2),
                 C1T=c(NA,  "Part of other business",   NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 C2=c(NA,   4,  1,  2,  4,  4,  3,  3,  NA),
                 C2T=c(NA,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 C3=c(3,    4,  3,  3,  6,  NA, 2,  4,  1),
                 C3T=c(NA,  NA, NA, NA, "two part are available but not in source", NA, NA, NA, NA),
                 C4=c(5,    5,  2,  NA, NA, 6,  4,  1,  2),
                 C5T=c(NA,  NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Critical Expert",  NA),
                 C5=c(6,    2,  6,  4,  2,  2,  5,  4,  1),
                 C5T=c(NA,  NA, NA, NA, NA, "most of things are stuck", "weather responsible",  NA, NA))


var <- "C1"
var1 <- "C1T"
var <- rlang::parse_expr(var)
var1 <- rlang::parse_expr(var1)
df1 <- df%>%filter(A1 == "class") 
T1<- df1 %>%group_by(B1)%>%summarise(mean=round(mean(!!var,na.rm = TRUE),1))
Comments <- df1 %>% group_by(B1) %>% summarise_at(vars(var1), paste0, collapse = " ") %>% 
  select(var1) %>% unlist() %>% gsub("NA","",.) %>% stringi::stri_trim_both()
cbind(T1,Comments)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited Answer:

```
var <- "C1"
var1 <- "C1T"
filtercol <- "A1"
filterval <- "class"
groupingvar <- "B1"

var <- rlang::parse_expr(var)
var1 <- rlang::parse_expr(var1)
filtercol <- rlang::parse_expr(filtercol)
groupingvar <- rlang::parse_expr(groupingvar)

library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>% filter(!!filtercol == filterval) 

T1 <- df1 %>% group_by(!!groupingvar) %>% summarise(mean=round(mean(as.numeric(!!var),na.rm = TRUE),1))
Comments <- df1 %>% select(!!groupingvar, !!var1) %>% 
  group_by(!!groupingvar) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(!!var1), paste0, collapse = " ") %>% 
  select(!!var1) %>% unlist() %>% gsub("NA", "", .) %>% 
  stringi::stri_trim_both()

T1 <- cbind(T1,Comments)
```

Comment: HOw can i modify the same for one column in my function, mean i can calculate what about comment ...???

Comment: for example like here mean is calculated but how can i add comments if there are more than one comments                      T1<-df1%>%group_by(groupingvar)%>%summarise(mean=round(mean(!!var,na.rm = TRUE),1))

Comment: What is "dat1"? It's not defined here.

Comment: var <- rlang::parse_expr(var)
var1 <- rlang::parse_expr(var1)
df1 <- df%>%filter(A1 == "class") 
T1<- df1 %>%group_by(B1)%>%summarise(mean=round(mean(!!var,na.rm = TRUE),1))
Comments <- df1 %>% summarise_at(!!var1, paste0, collapse = " ") %>% 
stringi::stri_trim_both() %>% unlist()
T1<-cbind(T1,Comments)    i  am trying like this bu not wirking, if one column can be done then i can ribind all result after loop for all columns

Comment: Comments <- df1 %>% summarise_at(var1, paste0, collapse = " ") %>% 
  gsub("NA","",.) %>% stringi::stri_trim_both() %>% unlist()

Comment: This should work:  Comments <- df1 %>%  group_by(B1) %>% summarise_at(vars(var1), paste0, collapse = " ") %>% 
  select(var1) %>% unlist() %>%  gsub("NA","",.) %>% stringi::stri_trim_both()

Comment: do you know if i am making it dynamic , what i am doing wrong here ...???
var <- "C1"
var1 <- "C1T"
var <- rlang::parse_expr(var)
var1 <- rlang::parse_expr(var1)
df1 <- df%>%filter(A1 == "class") 
T1<- df1 %>%group_by(B1)%>%summarise(mean=round(mean(!!var,na.rm = TRUE),1))
Comments <- df1 %>% summarise_at(!!var1, paste0, collapse = " ") %>% 
  gsub("NA","",.) %>% stringi::stri_trim_both() %>% unlist()

Comment: i tried this way but not working var <- "C1"
var1 <- "C1T"
var <- rlang::parse_expr(var)
var1 <- rlang::parse_expr(var1)
df1 <- df%>%filter(A1 == "class") 
T1<- df1 %>%group_by(B1)%>%summarise(mean=round(mean(!!var,na.rm = TRUE),1))
Comments <- df1 %>% group_by(B1) %>% summarise_at(vars(var1), paste0, collapse = " ") %>% 
  select(var1) %>% unlist() %>% gsub("NA","",.) %>% stringi::stri_trim_both()
cbind(T1,Comments)

Comment: Do you want to set the variables and values at each and every run? What about filtercol, is it fixed?

Comment: Yes, filtercol also i want to make it dynamic, so this is just a sub function for one column , i will iterate in next function for all columns

Comment: Give me a few minutes

Comment: Still comment column is Blank in output

Comment: forced to remove NA comments

Comment: I am sorry , i dont understand by  "forced to remove NA comments", my output is still blank in in comment column for CT1

Comment: When you filter A1 with "class", there is no comment in the column C1T

Answer (score 0):

**Update on OP's request (see comments):**

```
library(dplyr)

# helper function to coalesce by column
coalesce_by_column <- function(df) {
  return(coalesce(df[1], df[2]))
}

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    cols = contains("T"),
    names_to = "names",
    values_to = "values"
  ) %>% 
  filter(names == "C1T") %>% 
  group_by(names) %>% 
  summarise(Mean = mean(c_across(C1:C5 & where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE),
            Comments = coalesce_by_column(values))
```

Output:

```
  names  Mean Comments              
  <chr> <dbl> <chr>                 
1 C1T    3.47 Part of other business
```

**First answer**

1. `coalesce` to construct Comments column
2. `rowwise` with `c_across` to calculate the mean rowwise.
   In case you need to group, you can use ``group_by`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(Comments = coalesce(C1T, C2T, C3T, C4T, C5T),.keep="unused") %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Mean = mean(c_across(C1:C5 & where(is.numeric)), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  select(A1, B1, Mean, Comments)
```

Output:

```
  A1    B1     Mean Comments                                
  <chr> <chr> <dbl> <chr>                                   
1 class b2     5    NA                                      
2 type  b3     3.75 Part of other business                  
3 class b3     2.6  NA                                      
4 type  b1     3.75 NA                                      
5 class b3     4    two part are available but not in source
6 class b3     3.25 most of things are stuck                
7 class b3     4    weather responsible                     
8 class b2     3.6  Critical Expert                         
9 class b1     1.5  NA
```

Comment: I want to do it for one column only, if you se in expected output

Comment: I have updated a new version. Now it should work as desired!